# Accessing an ITypeInfo that references an ITypeInfo from an importlib-ed unregistered type library causes TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY error

Tags: c#, .net, ole, midl, ole-automation

I am using the Automation API from .NET (`System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes`) to inspect a type library `Bar.tlb` that I generated myself (see below). This type library declares an interface `IBar` which inherits from interface `IFoo` which is defined in an imported type library `Foo.tlb`. Inspecting the `ITypeInfo` representing `IBar` causes an exception. (Code follows below.)

Before I get to my code, here's how I generated the `Bar.tlb` type library.

#### Bar.idl:

```
[uuid(32E81FDD-BCB0-481B-AD3C-3ED04BFA7D1F)]
library Bar
{
    importlib("Foo.tlb");

    [uuid(CF062BE8-86D2-4D9B-8D1D-D889A77DA876)]
    interface IBar : IFoo { };
}
```

#### Foo.idl:

```
[uuid(22E81FDD-BCB0-481B-AD3C-3ED04BFA7D1E)]
library Foo
{
    importlib("stdole32.tlb");

    [uuid(BF062BE8-86D2-4D9B-8D1D-D889A77DA875)]
    interface IFoo : IUnknown { };
}
```

I compiled both IDL files using the following commands, which succeeded without any errors or warnings:

```
midl.exe /mktyplib203 /env win32 /i … /tlb Foo.tlb Foo.idl
midl.exe /mktyplib203 /env win32 /i … /tlb Bar.tlb Bar.idl
```

Now what I am trying to do is this:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using ITypeLib = System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.ITypeLib;
using ITypeInfo = System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.ITypeInfo;

static class Program
{
    [DllImport("oleaut32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, PreserveSig = false)]
    static extern ITypeLib LoadTypeLibEx(string path, REGKIND regkind);

    enum REGKIND { REGKIND_NONE = 2 }

    public static void Main()
    {
        ITypeLib typeLib = LoadTypeLibEx(@"C:\Path\To\Bar.tlb", REGKIND.REGKIND_NONE);
        ITypeInfo typeInfo;
        typeLib.GetTypeInfo(0, out typeInfo);
        IntPtr typeAttrPtr;
        typeInfo.GetTypeAttr(out typeAttrPtr); //! COMException: TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY
        …                                      //                (HRESULT 0x80029c4a)
    }
}
```

The exception is thrown on the line marked with `//!`. The inspected `ITypeInfo` is the one for the `IBar` interface.

I understand that the Automation API must have trouble locating the inherited interface `IFoo`, which is contained in a different type library that is also not registered.

But apparently it should be possible to inspect `Bar.tlb` anyway. `OleView.exe` manages just fine:

[image: Inspecting <code>Bar.tlb</code> in OleView works fine.]

(Yes, it gives a warning about not being able to reconstruct the external type library's filename, which is because I did not register `Foo.tlb`. That's not what I am worried about.)

If `OleView.exe` can inspect `IBar` without crashing, why does my code crash for something as simple as `typeInfo.GetTypeAttr()`? How do I fix this?

Comment: Oleview.exe can just display `<??filename??>` and makes no effort to display typeinfo from Foo.tlb.  That is not exactly an option when you use LoadTypeLibEx(), unless you likewise display such an error indication.  If you don't want an error then Foo.tlb needs to be registered so the COM plumbing can find it.  Assuming this is 32-bit code, the registry entries needs to be in HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Classes\Typelib.

Comment: @HansPassant: I did some more experimenting and found [a solution (answer below)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40752492/240733). I checked for the presence of a type library registration in the system registry, but couldn't find any additional entries, so it appears that my type libraries were not registered (like I requested by specifying `REGKIND_NONE`). Or could they get automatically unregistered when my process gets unloaded?

Comment: Well, that was a given when you get TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY.  You just did half of the job that makes type libraries useful.  You created one but unless you publish it so that other compilers and marshallers and interested-in-types whatnot code can find it back is a bit like a boomerang that doesn't come back: a stick.  Compare to .NET metadata, exact equivalent.  If you can't add a reference to a .NET assembly either by selecting it with the Browse button or from the pre-cooked list then it is a stick as well.

Comment: @HansPassant: I can see what you mean. However, I'm not actually going to publish any type library of my own. I'm only learning how to use the Automation API to consume existing ones, in order to create a tool for generating customized .NET interop types from such a type library. I simply got sidetracked here by my own curiosity when I realised that the Automation API does not have any method or structure that corresponds directly to IDL `importlib` statements, yet OleView can decompile them somehow. But I've now figured out how OleView does this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR:** The Automation API appears to access type libraries in the current working directory behind the scenes in order to resolve `ITypeInfo` references. The issue can be resolved by doing this:

```
// using static System.IO.Directory;
SetCurrentDirectory(@"C:\Path\To");
ITypeLib typeLib = LoadTypeLibEx("Bar.tlb", REGKIND.REGKIND_NONE);
```

instead of:

```
ITypeLib typeLib = LoadTypeLibEx(@"C:\Path\To\Bar.tlb", REGKIND.REGKIND_NONE);
```

---

I experimented some more and found out that `OleView.exe` can only successfully inspect `IBar` type details in `Bar.tlb` if `Foo.tlb` is present in the same directory. Once I move `Foo.tlb` off somewhere else, `OleView.exe` fails just like my own code does:

[image: Same COM error occurs in <code>OleView.exe</code> once <code>Foo.tlb</code> is moved away from <code>Bar.tlb</code>]

I wanted to see which API calls `OleView.exe` used to access type libraries, so I checked:

```
dumpbin.exe /imports OleView.exe
dumpbin.exe /exports C:\WINDOWS\…\oleaut32.dll
```

and found that it references `LoadTypeLib` — not `LoadTypeLibEx`. The two functions differ in how they do type library registration. So I looked up the [MSDN documentation for `LoadTypeLib`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221027.aspx) and found this:

> *"`LoadTypeLib` will not register the type library if the path of the type library is specified."*

Which gave me the idea to rewrite my code as shown at the beginning of this answer.

It's important however to point out that contrary to what the quoted text suggests, it is not the presence or absence of a directory in the path passed to `LoadTypeLibEx` — **it's the call to `Directory.SetCurrentDirectory` that resolves the error.** The following would work as well:

```
// using static System.IO.Directory;
SetCurrentDirectory(@"C:\Path\To");
ITypeLib typeLib = LoadTypeLibEx("C:\Path\To\Bar.tlb", REGKIND.REGKIND_NONE);
```